# Php create array with associative values and count

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with this structure

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [profileId] => 1000000407
            [locationId] => 207

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [profileId] => 1000000407
            [locationId] => 250

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [profileId] => 1000000398
            [locationId] => 250

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [profileId] => 1000000393
            [locationId] => 250

        )
    [4] => Array
            (
             [profileId] => 1000000393
             [locationId] => 250

            )
)
```

From this array I would like to create a new array with the location Ids as the key and have the array containing the count of the profileId associated with that location.
So in this instance I need to return

```
Array
(
   [207] => Array
        (
         [1000000407] => 1
        )
   [250] => Array
        (
         [1000000407] => 1
         [1000000398] => 1
         [1000000393] => 2
        )
)
```

I appreciate this might be quite simple, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: In order to stop people from downvoting you need to put what you have tried so far

Comment: loop using `foreach`, create new array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually use `array_reduce` for these tasks, like this:

```
$new = array_reduce(
     $old,
     function($result, $item) 
     {
         $result[$item['locationId']][$item['profileId']] += 1;
         return $result;
     }
)
```

Comment: Elegant solution. I tested it here http://www.tehplayground.com/#3g6tHl4JV (without the lines 29...32 your solution would throw warnings, you need to ensure those indexes are defined before incrementing them)

Comment: I guess not warnings - notices, but you still got your point.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is...

```
$main = array(
    array(
            'profileId' => 1000000407,
            'locationId' => 207

        ),

    array(
            'profileId' => 1000000407,
            'locationId' => 250

        ),

    array(
            'profileId' => 1000000398,
            'locationId' => 250

        ),

    array(
            'profileId' => 1000000393,
            'locationId' => 250

        ),
    array(
             'profileId' => 1000000393,
             'locationId' => 250

            )
);

$output = array();

foreach ($main as $node)
{
    if ( ! isset($output[$node['locationId']]))
    {
        $output[$node['locationId']] = array();
    }

    if ( ! isset($output[$node['locationId']][$node['profileId']]))
    {
        $output[$node['locationId']][$node['profileId']] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        $output[$node['locationId']][$node['profileId']]++;
    }
}

print_r($output);
```

Answer (score 1):

This may do what you want

```
$locationId = '';
$counter = 1;
$new_arr = array();
$profileId = '';
foreach($my_arr as $row)
{
    if($row['locationId'] != $locationId)
    {
        $locationId = $row['locationId'];
        $profileId = $row['profileId'];
        $new_arr[$row['locationId']] = array($row['profileId'] => $counter);
    }
    else
    {
        if($row['profileId'] != $profileId)
        {
           $profileId = $row['profileId'];
           $counter = 1;
        }
        else
        {
           $counter++;
        }
        $new_arr[$row['locationId']][$row['profileId']] = $counter;
    }
}
```